# case when in update query MySQL PDO

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

How to run update query in MySQL and PDO using `CASE WHEN`.
the following query updates `CASE` columns with 0.

```
$query= "Update payments SET 
                            total = :total,
                            paid = CASE
                                      WHEN paid > :new THEN paid = :new
                                   ELSE paid
                                   END,
                            due = CASE
                                     WHEN paid < :new THEN due = :new - paid
                                  ELSE due
                                  END
                             WHERE id = :id ";

                        $update= $db->prepare($query);

                        $update->bindparam(':total',$new);
                        $update->bindparam(':new',$new);
                        $update->bindparam(':id',$id);
                        $update->execute();
```

Comment: Should it be `THEN :new` instead of `THEN paid = :new`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

dont try to assign the value to your column inside the CASE WHEN statements since you are already doing that.
the CASE WHEN will evaluate to the value that satisfies the condition.
try this code

```
UPDATE payments SET 
 total = :total,
 paid = (CASE WHEN paid > :new THEN :new ELSE paid END),
 due = (CASE WHEN paid < :new THEN (:new - paid) ELSE due END)
 WHERE id = :id
```

I removed the assignments to paid and due columns inside the case statement.